# LinearLayout vs RelativeLayout ANR crash

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-anr-dialog, android-relativelayout

I'm making a stopwatch app, so I have multiple constantly updating TextViews text where I update the text showing the clock time.

The original layout was multiple layers of LinearLayouts to help me lay things out. It got complicated so I switched to RelativeLayout, which Google even recommends to improve performance.
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

However, I start to get ANR crashes after doing so. Why would a more efficient layout be giving me ANR?

Related code, also on another note, I can't seem to get the ANR anymore...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_times_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Time&apos;s \n Up!"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_clock_hide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_clock_hr"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_digit_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_clock_colon1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_colon_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_clock_min"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_digit_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_clock_colon2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_colon_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_clock_sec"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_digit_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_clock_milli"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_milli_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
            android:text="000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</merge>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_times_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Time&apos;s \n Up!"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_clock_hide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clock_hr"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_digit_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clock_colon1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_colon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_clock_hr"
        android:text=":"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clock_min"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_digit_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_clock_colon1"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clock_colon2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_colon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_clock_min"
        android:text=":"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clock_sec"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_digit_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_clock_colon2"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clock_milli"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/clock_milli_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clock_digit_height"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_clock_sec"
        android:text="000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: you may be blocking the ui thread or doing ui operation in a thread

Comment: Post related code. And logcat

Comment: changing layouts and getting ANR are different. Please check the code.